# React Final Form - Double conditional Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I have started to work on a form project using React final form, but I am struggling to do a two condition question.

Would anyone knows how to do a double conditional logic on React final form. From this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lm4p3m92q?file=/src/index.js:849-910), the single conditional logic code is given :

```
const Condition = ({ when, is, children }) => ( <Field name={when} subscription={{ value: true }}>
{({ input: { value } }) => (value === is ? children : null)}  </Field>)
```

However, I don't know how to do a double conditional one that would require 2 different answers from two different questions in the form to be checked before displaying the conditional question.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `useFormState` from `react-final-form` to obtain current form state, so `MultiCondition` component could look like this:

```
const MultiCondition = ({ condition, children }) => {
  const { values = {} } = useFormState({ subscription: { values: true } });
  return condition(values) ? children : null;
};
```

than somewhere inside the form:

```
<MultiCondition condition={({ gift, firstName }) => gift && firstName === "Joe"}>
  <span>gets rendered when condition is satisfied</span>
</MultiCondition>
```